# create db2 user with read-only access in AIX

Tags: db2, aix

I´m using db2 on AIX.
I created the user usrxxxxx with read-only permissions.

The problem is that i can´t start db2 with this user.

su - usrxxxxx

$ db2

ksh: db2:  not found.

$

I also grant select permissions to user usrxxxxx with user db2inst1.
e.g.grant select on tbl_data1 to usrxxxxx

I dont know if i am missing a step. I really appreciate your help. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

In order to execute db2 commands in the server, you need to load the db2profile.

For example, if your instance name is 'db2inst1' and the home is at '/home/db2inst1' you need to do:

```
. /home/db2inst1/sqllib/db2profile
```

This will load the DB2 profile in you current session and then you can execute db2 commands.

However, the user used to execute commands needs to have the necessary privilges. For example, in order to start the instance, the user should be part of one group that has the SYSADM, SYSCTRL or SYSMAINT authority. Check the [InfoCenter-db2start](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v10r5/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.cmd.doc/doc/r0001982.html)

I recommend you to check the authorities (at instance and database level) and the privileges, in order to understand how DB2 security works. A tutorial [here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/tutorials/db2-cert7302/section2.html)